# Scikit-learn installation: "ImportError: No module named sklearn"

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, installation, scikit-learn

I've been trying my hand at machine learning and I've installed scikit-learn through anaconda, but when I try to import from sklearn, my interpreter gives me an ImportError. When I try

```
python setup.py install
```

in my site-packages/sklearn directory, I get this error:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5/src
creating build/temp.macosx-10.5-x86_64-3.5/src/libsvm
compile options: '-I/Users/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/core/include -c'
g++: src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
clang: error: no such file or directory: 'src/libsvm/libsvm_template.cpp'
clang: error: no input files
```

I was able to download SciPy, NumPy, and nltk so not sure if there would be a dependency issue.

I'm not very familiar with Python packages and scikit-learn. **Does anyone know what this error means / how to proceed?**

Comment: What were the commands you issued to download/install sklearn, numpy, scipy, etc? Are you able to import Numpy, Scipy, etc just fine? Have you ever installed numpy and scipy via pip or easy_install?

Comment: @NBartley I originally installed miniconda and then used conda command to install sklearn, numpy, and scipy. Regardless of whether I use miniconda or anaconda, installing places sklearn, numpy, etc in a separate folder with that name -- i tried moving them into my python library folder under systems and frameworks but that didn't work. I import Numpy, Scipy just fine. (ty!)

Comment: *"Regardless of whether I use miniconda or anaconda, installing places sklearn, numpy, etc in a separate folder with that name"* - that is how `conda` is *supposed* to work. The modules should be installed in a subdirectory of `anaconda/pkgs`. You do not need to move directories around or call `python setup.py install`. I suggest you start again with a fresh installation of Anaconda/Miniconda, since the one you have is probably broken now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install libsvm. In linux is something like this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsvm-dev libsvm3 python-libsvm
```

You might have more uninstalled libraries. If they are python packages you can install them with `pip`. Please take a look at this [guide](http://python-packaging-user-guide.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing/).

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a lot of things but finally, including uninstall with the automated tools. So, I've uninstalled manually scikit-learn.

```
sudo rm -R /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn
sudo rm -R /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scikit_learn-0.20.0-py3.6.egg-info
```

And re-install using pip

```
sudo pip3.6 install -U scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

Don’t bother using setup.py files for manual installation unless you really have a specific reason for it. Just install Anaconda (a package manager) and use

> conda install

In fact, it comes preinstalled with sklearn!